# make treesitter match classname

Tags: java, parsing, clojure, treesitter

I am using [Treesitter](http://tree-sitter.github.io/tree-sitter/) to parse Clojure code. Specifically I would like to distinguish between symbols, class names and [Java Interop](https://clojure.org/reference/java_interop).

This is my grammar:

```
module.exports = grammar({
    name: 'clojure',
    extras: $ => [/[\s,]/],
    rules: {
        program: $ => repeat($._anything),
        _anything: $ => choice($.symbol, $.classname, $.member_access, $.new_class),

        symbol: $ => $._symbol_chars,

        classname: $ => prec.left(3, seq($._symbol_chars, repeat1($._classname_part ))),
        _classname_part: $ => prec.right(3, seq($._dot, $._symbol_chars)),

        member_access: $ => seq($._dot, $._class_chars),
        new_class: $ => prec(2, seq( choice($.symbol, $.classname), $._dot)),

        _dot: $ => /\.{1}/,
        _symbol_chars: $ =>   /[a-zA-Z\*\+\!\-_\?][\w\*\+\!\-\?\':]*/,
        _class_chars: $ => /[a-zA-Z_]\w*/
    }
})
```

I would expect

```
foo
java.lang.String
.toUpperCase
java.awt.Point.
```

to be parsed to

```
(program (
    (symbol)
    (classname)
    (member_access)
    (new_class (classname)))
```

But Treesitter keeps seeing `(new_class (classname)) (classname)` instead of `(classname)` for `Java.lang.String`. I suppose that I need some kind of greedy matching and have tried  `prec.right()` in different places to no avail. What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm a tree-sitter newbie, so please take that into account when processing the following :)

`extras` contains whitespace for this grammar.  IIUC, this means that if one does not use `token` around `seq` appropriately, tree-sitter will try to account for cases where whitespace can occur between items in a `seq`.

For example, for:

```
seq($._dot, $._class_chars)
```

tree-sitter will try to treat as valid `$._dot` and `$._class_chars` being separated by whitespace.  But IIUC that is not necessarily equivalent in Clojure to the case where they are not separated by whitespace.

It appears that `token` cannot be used everywhere though, so just putting it around the above sorts of uses of `seq` may not work.  My guess is that, roughly, if all arguments to `seq` are tokens, `token` may be used around `seq`.

Below is an example that appears to handle the 4 test cases provided.  Although what things are parsed to precisely differs, one can still make the appropriate distinctions, AFAICT.

```
const JAVA_ID = /[a-zA-Z_]\w*/;

module.exports = grammar({

    name: 'clojure',

    extras: $ =>
        [/[\s,]/],

    rules: {
        program: $ =>
            repeat($._anything),

        _anything: $ =>
            choice($.symbol,
                   $.member_access,
                   $.new_class),

        symbol: $ =>
            choice($._symbol_chars,
                   $.scoped_identifier),

        // XXX: approximate, see: https://clojure.org/reader
        _symbol_chars: $ =>
            /[a-zA-Z\*\+\!\-_\?][\w\*\+\!\-\?\':]*/,

        // XXX: except $ can be used too for inner classes?
        scoped_identifier: $ =>
            token(seq(JAVA_ID,
                      repeat(seq('.', JAVA_ID)))),

        // e.g. .toUpperCase
        member_access: $ =>
            token(seq('.',
                      JAVA_ID,
                      repeat(seq('.', JAVA_ID)))),

        // e.g. java.lang.String.
        new_class: $ =>
            token(seq(JAVA_ID,
                      repeat(seq('.', JAVA_ID)),
                      '.')),

    }
});

function sep1 (rule, separator) {
    return seq(rule, repeat(seq(separator, rule)));
}
```

Note that the version of tree-sitter-cli may matter -- I used 0.16.4.  When I tried your grammar, I didn't get the same output you did.

(The `scoped_identifier` bit was somewhat inspired by something of the same name from tree-sitter-java's grammar.)

(On a side note, ATM it appears that questions about tree-sitter are being fielded at the tree-sitter github repository.  There have been some issues there mentioning the possibility of other places for discussion, but I haven't seen anything come about yet.  You might get better answers there.)

Comment: What I had been missing was the use of `token`. This is the Answer I was looking for. Thank you!